# Evaluate specific cells in Mathematica

Tags: bugs, cells

I have a very simple problem with Mathematica that I couldn't find an easy answer to.
I have long notebook with a lot of cells and want to evaluate a specific cells inline from another cell.

So far I have been trying to put tags on the cells and then use:
NotebookEvaluate[EvaluationNotebook[], EvaluationElements -> "Tags" -> {tag1, tag2,..}]

I thought that this should do it, but instead it always evaluates the whole notebook and gets stuck in a loop.
Is there something slightly wrong, or a trick with the tag names?
Or am I doing something conceptually wrong?

Btw it works fine if I use the option EvaluationElements-> "InitializationCell"
but doesn't work properly with the "Tags" option.

Comment: possible bug. With V9 on OS X I get repeated (endless loop) print statements

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Read the [faq]!
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge.
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: I can reproduce the problem in V9.0.1 on Win7/64.  It evaluates all elements in the notebook, ignoring the `EvaluationElements`.  If the `NotebookEvaluate` expression is in the target notebook, it loops indefinitely.  In V10.0.2 it works properly, even from within the same notebook.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming you are doing this in the same notebook then:

```
nb = EvaluationNotebook[];
NotebookFind[nb, "tag1", All, CellTags]
SelectionEvaluate[nb]
```

If you have several tagged cells that you want to evaluate then

```
(NotebookFind[nb, #, All, CellTags];SelectionEvaluate[nb]) & /@ {"tag1", "tag2"}
```

**Edit**

The above is the way I would normally do it because it predates the addition of `EvaluationElements`. I tried that method and it failed in V9. Additionally the example in the docs fails (V9 OS X) which seems a good enough reason to call this a V9 bug.

Contrary to earlier edit this is now working in V10.

Comment: +1.  When I tried it in V10.0.2 (Win 7/64) it worked perfectly, evaluating all (and only) tagged cells.  `NotebookEvaluate` is defined to return only the value from the last evaluation, so it is hard to see the failure from just the screenshot since none of the cells have visible side-effects.  Does it fail if the evaluated cells contain `Print` expressions, or the `InsertResults -> True` option is included?

Comment: @WReach you are correct. It is working okay in V10. It looks like a V9 bug only -- fixed in 10.

Comment: Thank you Mike, your solution works for me. I am indeed using V9 so there seems to be a bug with the EvaluationElements option. But your workaround does give the desired result in V9. Thanks a lot!