# How to assign a tag to a cell

Tags: cells

I want to assign each cell in my current notebook a tag so that I can rerun cells with specific tags later in the notebook [(Using a method similar to this answer)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/71333/44420).

My questions are

- How do I assign cells in my current notebook tags?
- How  do I view the tags that I have assigned?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the menu item `Cell | CellTags` to do this. If you want to inspect and modify [`CellTags`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CellTags) programmatically, you can use [`CurrentValue`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CurrentValue) and [`SetOptions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SetOptions). For example:

```
cell = PreviousCell[];
CurrentValue[cell, CellTags]
```

> {}

Change the tag:

```
SetOptions[cell, CellTags->"FOO"]
```

Check:

```
CurrentValue[cell, CellTags]
```

> "FOO"

Another useful function is [`Cells`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Cells), which will return a list of [`Cell`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Cell) objects satisfying various criteria.

Answer (score 1):

For thoose looking at this question in the future if you want to label the first 3 input cells cell tags use the following

```
{cell1, cell2, cell3} = Cells[CellStyle -> {"Input"}][[1 ;; 3]]
SetOptions[cell1, CellTags -> {"FOO"}]
SetOptions[cell2, CellTags -> {"FOO2"}]
SetOptions[cell3, CellTags -> {"FOO3"}]
(*Check cell tags*)
CurrentValue[{cell1, cell2, cell3}, CellTags]
```