# How to launch specific section of the Mathematica notebook depending on the dialog choice?

Tags: syntax, dialog-window

Consider some Mathematica notebook where there is some preliminary code followed by chapters, sections, and subsections that must be evaluated using the code. Say, there are `Chapter 1`, `Chapter 2`, where there are sections `1.1`, `1.2`, and the subsections `1.1.1` (in `1.1`), `1.2.1`, `1.2.2` (in `1.2`).

Would it be possible to

1. Associate the chapters, sections, and sub-sections with some
   parameters (say, `Chapter 1` -> "A", `Chapter 2` -> "B"), (`1.1` ->
   "First", `1.2` -> "Second"), (`1.1.1` -> "Green", `1.2.1` -> "Yellow 1", `1.2.2` -> "Yellow 2"),
2. Launch only the subsection associated with the given keys entered in a dialog window? Say, if I subsequently choose "A", "First", "Green", then the subsection `Chapter 1/1.1/1.1.1` will be launched?

**Edit**

I have found [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/71332/evaluate-specific-cells-in-mathematica). So I select the particular cell including `Chapter 1` and just some equality `x = 12` below, add the tag "Chapter 1" in Cells/Cell tags/Add/remove cell tags, and use the following code:

```
nb = EvaluationNotebook[];
(NotebookFind[nb, #, All, CellTags]; 
   SelectionEvaluate[nb]) & /@ {"Chapter 1"}
```

As far as I understand, there is a possibility to add particular tags for sections and sub-sections inside the chapter, and that's it. If there are elegant solutions for this problem, I would appreciate any help.

Comment: It's probably better to split it into different notebooks (under the same kernel) and have it open and evaluate that particular notebook instead.

Comment: You can select a whole cell group.  E.g. run this in a doc page for any standard function: `NotebookFind[EvaluationNotebook[], "Scope"];
SelectionMove[EvaluationNotebook[], All, CellGroup]`.  `CellTags` are probably safer than text search, but you need only tag the chapter heading cells.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
evaluateGroupDialog := 
 DynamicModule[{sel = {}, 
   types = {"Title", "Chapter", "Section", "Subsection", 
     "Subsubsection"}, cells, inputs, group},
  cells = 
   Association[
    Table[type -> 
      Select[Cells[], 
       CurrentValue[#, "CellStyle"] == {type} &], {type, types}]];
  inputs = 
   Table[{type, 
     PopupMenu[
      Dynamic[sel], (# -> First@NotebookRead[#]) & /@ 
       cells[type]]}, {type, types}];
  
  group = DialogInput[Grid[{{"Select group to evaluate", ""},
      Sequence @@ inputs, {CancelButton[], 
       DefaultButton["Evaluate", DialogReturn[sel]]}}, 
     Alignment -> Left], Modal -> True];
  
  If[group =!= $Canceled,
   SelectionMove[group, All, CellGroup];
   SelectionEvaluate[InputNotebook[]]
   ];
  ]

evaluateGroupDialog;
```

[image: Group selector]